# Github actions configure AWS credentials throws error

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, cloud, github-actions, amazon-ecr

I am trying to build docker image and upload it to AWS ECR using Github actions. Had referred articles online and came up with an action file with one of its step as:

```
- name: Configure AWS credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.ROLE }}
    aws-region: us-west-2
```

When I run the workflow, I get an error at this step saying "Error: The security token included in the request is invalid." even though I have provided the correct credentials. What am I missing here?

I wanted to get it connected and move to the next step, which is:

```
- name: Login to Amazon ECR
    id: login-ecr
    uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

- name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
  env:
    ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
    ECR_REPOSITORY: test
    IMAGE_TAG: test_new
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there was a bug in the aws-sdk-js recently regarding this, but should be resolved. see https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/issues/585  and https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4286

Comment: Hello @Akshaya Jai! Any progress on this issue, please? I am dealing with the very same one, and I am kind of lost, now. :/

Comment: The solution is to add aws-session-token in the configure AWS credentials section. It worked for me.